# After Azure VM deployment it returns http error 307

Tags: azure, deployment

With ruby 2.0 and azure 0.7.5 I created a VM and even after deployment scceeded it returns
http error: 307 . Any ideas ?

Storage Account portalvhds6vgyjqvx1v9k8 already exists. Skipped...
Deployment in progress...

## # # # # # # # #  succeeded (200)

http error: 307

Comment: Not sure about this, but seems like you are trying to create VM which uses the already existing storage. The storage acts like hard drive where the VM is installed, so try deploying the VM to empty storage.

Comment: Thanks Sopuli , any idea why this happens even when calling the list of VMs

Comment: if vm_mgr.nil?
                  vm_mgr = Azure::VirtualMachineManagement::VirtualMachineManagementService.new
                end
                #new_vm = vm_mgr.get_virtual_machine(vm_name,cloud_service)
                vm_list = vm_mgr.list_virtual_machines
                if !vm_list.nil?
                  new_vm = vm_list.find { |x| x.vm_name == instanceid }
                end

Answer (score 0):

It seems Azure sometimes return 307 (Temporary Redirect). The workaround is to call the function again until it doesn't return 307

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/129
(this bug is filed for the Python SDK but I have seen it in other SDKs as well)

Hopefully they will fix this at some point